# ionic splashscreen not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i just see a gray screen as splashscreen in android for 1 or maybe 2 seconds.. but surely not the 3 seconds i gave in config.xml

i actually spent hours of trying and trying but i dont get it work.
(plugin reinstalls, ionic state resets)

i dont know if its working on ios (i dont have a mac)

here is my config: (C:\myproject\config.xml)
[image: config.xml]

and here is my ionic info output:

[image]

best regards
Harald

Comment: splashscreen is not working in ionic.
don't know the reason.i am too waiting for reply.
thank you for questioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!! i simply forgot to call:
$cordovaSplashscreen.show();

:bash: :bash: :bash:

in the controller of my first visible view!

Comment: change, sorry it wasnt the $cordovaSplashscreen.show(); it was the downgrade to plugin version 2.0.0 which i found in a other topic

Answer (score 0):

Did you try regenerating the resources folder with required splash screen and logo as per ionic documentation? Please ensure the size of image and type is as per document. I verified my config.xml and its same. So please confirm on above two points.

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer. i used the given template from ionic(with the green lines, and i painted my logo within) after that i used the command "ionic resources" to generate the folder.

Comment: while compiling i see a red line: :compileDebugJavaWithJavacNote: C:\myproject\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. maybe this is the problem?